# What is the difference between "scalar types" and "Numpy numerical types"?

Tags: python, numpy

I was reading about the data types in Numpy and then got confused by the two following statements:

[1](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html) NumPy numerical types are instances of dtype (data-type) objects, each having unique characteristics.

[2](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) Note that the scalar types are not dtype objects, even though they can be used in place of one whenever a data type specification is needed in NumPy.

What is the difference between "scalar types" and "Numpy numerical types"? if they are the same, so scalar types are data-type objects or not?

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` wraps C level arrays. Python never sees the values in the array directly because they are not python objects (or don't need to be). For instance,

```
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

is a python object (`np.array`) that internally manages 3 C level integers contiguous in memory. If you reference one of these

```
val = arr[1]
```

well, you can't do that directly, because C level integers are not python integers. Instead you get a `numpy.int64` (or whatever `numpy.int_` is mapped to). Numpy created a python object holding the value that python can use. That is the scalar numpy is talking about. The numerical type is the single C level type of an array of values in memory and the corresponding scalar is the python object type used when python interacts with that array.

This is not terribly efficient - you only reference individual elements of an array when you really have to.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I didn't understand it. Could you please explain it in simple terms? I appreciate it.